# How to allow the user to only write numbers between 00 and 24

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Here is my problem: I'd like to allow the user to write only numbers between 00 and 24.

Js code :

```
const putRealTime = () => {
    const hoursRangePattern = /^(2[0-3]|1[0-9]|[0-9])$/;

    document.querySelector(".hour-min-input").addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
        if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    })

    document.querySelector(".hour-min-input").addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
        const eKey = parseInt(e.key)
        if (hoursRangePattern.test(eKey)) {
            e.preventDefault()
        }
    })
}
```

Ruby code :

```
            <div class="hours-container-1">
              <p class="">Your event will start at :</p>
              <div class="hours-container-2 align-items-end">
                <%= f.input :min_timeh, label: false, placeholder: "hh", input_html: { min: '0', max: '24', step: '1' }, input_html: { class: 'hour-min-input', maxlength: 2 }%>
                <p class="double-point">:</p>
                <%= f.input :min_timem, label: false, placeholder:"mm", input_html: { min: '0', max: '59', step: '1' }, input_html: { class: 'min-min-input', maxlength: 2 }%>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wish my regex-fu skills were better...

```js
const input = document.querySelector(".hour-min-input")

const putRealTime = () => {

    input.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
        const key = event.key;
        const value = event.target.value;
        const length = value.length;
        
        if (key === "Backspace") {
          return;
        }

        if((length === 0 && !/^[0-2]$/g.test(key))
        || (length === 1 && Number(value) === 1 && !/^[0-9]$/g.test(key))
        || (length === 1 && Number(value) === 2 && !/^[0-3]$/g.test(key))
        || (length >= 2)
        ) {
          return event.preventDefault()
        }
        
    })
}

putRealTime();
```

```html
<input type="text" class="hour-min-input">
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `f.input`, so I assume you have `gem 'simple_form'` installed.
In simple_form:

```
= f.input :min_timeh, label: false, placeolder: "hh", collection: 0..23
= f.input :min_timem, label: false, placeolder: "mm", collection: 0..59
```

You do not need extra javascript for this.

Additionally, you can add the following validation to your Model that contains the 2 columns `min_timeh` & `min_timem`:

```
validates :min_timeh, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 23 }
validates :min_timem, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 59 }
```

If you do want to make the validation more "fancy", here's a gem https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations

Comment: This solution is the simplest one, I agree but I'm looking for a different visual. The user should be  able to write a number and not to pick it. thank you anyway

Comment: for the user to write the number, just remove `, collection: 0..23`. If you are looking for something more specific, specify it in your question. "I'd like to allow the user to write only numbers between 00 and 24." is not specific

Comment: You're right! was my first question sorry. Thank you for helping me anyway.

Answer (score 1):

On your `keypress` events you will want to validate the input value, to access the value something like:

```js
document.querySelector(".hour-min-input").addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
  const value = Math.min(24, Math.max(0, e.target.value));
  e.target.value = value;
  const eKey = parseInt(e.key)
  if (hoursRangePattern.test(eKey)) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
})
```

Bundle up those 2 new lines in a function that takes an event/min/max as a set of arguments and apply it to both events returned by the event listener callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

in js you can some thing like:

```
var regexp, x;
x = $(this).val();
regexp = /([01][0-9]|[2][0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/;
if (!regexp.test(x)) {
  return $(this).val("00:00");
}
```

note: for regexp pattern:

- first part "[01][0-9]" if first digit between 0 or 1 then second digit can be between 0..9
- or second part "[2][0-3]" if first digit 2 then second digit must between 0..3
- third part [0-5][0-9] for minute it's only allow between 00 - 59
- if it's not pass the regexp then we overwrite with 00:00